# Web Scraping Youtube URL on Genius with Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am using request along with cheerio to try to grab the link to a song on genius.com. The URL should be a YouTube link. The problem is that I simply cannot get the 'a' element to return its href attribute. This is my code (cheerio and request are loaded farther up in the script).

```
request('https://genius.com/Eminem-the-monster-lyrics' , function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var url = $('a' , 'div.song_media_controls-provider-icon').attr('href');

    }
    console.log(url);
});
```

[image: This is a screenshot of the HTML that I'm scraping.]

I apologize if its a stupid problem or a stupid post. I'm still learning with all of this. Thank you to anyone for help.

Comment: are you facing some kind of error like cross domain?

Comment: that whole block of html containing the desired `<a>`  is in an angular directive (`<ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="secondary">`) which means it's probably not loaded when you scrape the page. You'd have to use selenium or something which will allow you access to events and deferred code execution which isn't nearly as straight forward a proposition as using cheerio. [here's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) some more info.

Comment: i think you trying to get different domain url in your call. 
try this one may be it will help you:-

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery cross domain ajax
$.get("https://genius.com/Eminem-the-monster-lyrics").done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// using XMLHttpRequest
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://genius.com/Eminem-the-monster-lyrics", true);
xhttp.send();
</script>

Comment: you also need to add Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * extension for chrome b'coz our code only on client side.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// jQuery cross domain ajax
$.get("https://genius.com/Eminem-the-monster-lyrics").done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// using XMLHttpRequest
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://genius.com/Eminem-the-monster-lyrics", true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>NK Chaudhary</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="demo"><a href="/">Add here genius.com</a></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```